# Updating FancyBox Form with Ajax Postback

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I currently have a partial view that automatically triggers a fancybox popup when you load the page.  This part works, and the window opens and displays the data.

When I click a button, I post back to the controller which saves the data, then returns the same partial view with the new view model object.

I'm able to post back to the controller ok, but when the partial view is returned I can't seem to update the view of the fancybox window.  I want the window to update or refresh with the new data, however it still contains the old data.

**Partial View that's loaded into fancybox popup:**

```
<form id="formSurvey">
            <span>@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.UserAnswer1, new { style = "width:300px;", maxlength = "250", name = "Answer1", id = "Answer1" })</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller Action:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SurveySave(SurveyDTO Survey)
    {
        //save data here

        SurveyViewModel svm = new SurveyViewModel();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Survey/Survey.cshtml", svm);
    }
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load(function () {
    $.fancybox("#formSurvey");
});

function clickedClose(e) {
    $.fancybox.close();
}
function clickedNext(e, formDiv) {
    var SurveyDTO = {
        Question1: $('#Question1Field').val(),
        Question2: $('#Question2Field').val(),
        Answer1: $('#Answer1').val(),
        Answer2: $('#Answer2').val(),

    };
    var sURL = '@Url.Action("SurveySave", "Home")'
    $.ajax({
        url: sURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Survey' : SurveyDTO }),
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

I know I need to handle the data returned and reload into Fancybox.  I'm not sure if I need to convert the form into an AJAX form, or if there is another way to refresh the already opened fancybox window.  Thanks

Comment: You specifying `dataType: 'json',` but the method returns html, not json, so this code would be throwing an error. It needs to be `dataType: 'html'` and then you need to replace the existing html with the new html you have returned.

Comment: But if you just want to update the values of existing controls, then just return json containing the values and update the values of the controls.

Comment: Would it make more sense if I just return the data as json:            [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SurveySave(SurveyDTO Survey)
        {
            SurveyViewModel svm = new SurveyViewModel();
            return Json(svm);
        }

Comment: Probably, but I do not know what you want to update. And since all your returning is a new instance of `SurveyViewModel` then what is the point anyway (why not just clear the form controls?). You have not given enough information to understand what you actually want to do.

Comment: All I want to do is update the questions.  The surveyviewmodel updates the question values via constructor.

Comment: The all you need to do is pass only the relevant properties/values using an anonymous object - there is no point sending extra data. For example `return Json(new { Question1 = "xxx", Question2 = "yyy" });` and in the ajax success callback, `$(someElement).val(data.Question1);` etc